# How can I get the correct urls of ads?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the urls of the ads on `"Marktplaats"` website (link is provided below).

As you can see I'm looking for 30 URLs. These URLs are placed inside a `'href'` field and all start with `"/a/auto-s/"`. Unfortunately, I only keep getting the first few URLs. I found out that on this sites all the data is places within `"<li class = "mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item"> ... </li>"`. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it? (you can see that you won't find all the URLs of the ads when you run my code)

Link:

```
https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/#f:10882,10898|PriceCentsTo:350000|constructionYearFrom:2001|offeredSince:TODAY|searchInTitleAndDescription:true
```

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/#f:10882,10898|PriceCentsTo:350000|constructionYearFrom:2001|offeredSince:TODAY|searchInTitleAndDescription:true"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
url_list = soup.find_all(class_ = 'mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item')

print(url_list)
```

Comment: There's no `"mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item"` in response, open "page source" in browser and check.

Comment: [Here](https://www.marktplaats.nl/lrp/api/search?attributeRanges[]=PriceCents%3Anull%3A350000&attributeRanges[]=constructionYear%3A2001%3Anull&attributesById[]=10882&attributesById[]=10898&l1CategoryId=91&limit=30&offset=0&searchInTitleAndDescription=true&viewOptions=list-view) is correct url which returns search result. **Don't forget to ask website owner for permission to use this data!**

Comment: Btw, they have official [api](https://api.marktplaats.nl/docs/v1/index.html)...

Comment: Olvin, just one more question. With what python code did you get the correct url that returns the search result?

Comment: I've opened browser developer tools (press f12 on page), switched to tab "Network" and refreshed page (press f5). Then I've checked list of requests sent by browser and found correct by looking for substring in responses. Alternatively you can use any sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_links(url):
    links = []
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    for li in soup.find_all(class_="mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item"):
        links.append(li.a.get('href'))
    return links

url = "https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/#f:10882,10898|PriceCentsTo:350000|constructionYearFrom:2001|offeredSince:TODAY|searchInTitleAndDescription:true"
links = parse_links(url)
print('\n'.join(map(str, links)))
```

**Output**

```
/a/auto-s/oldtimers/a1302359148-allis-chalmers-ed40-1965.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/a1258166221-opel-movano-2-3-cdti-96kw-2018.html
/a/auto-s/oldtimers/a1302359184-chevrolet-biscayne-bel-air-1960.html
/a/auto-s/renault/a1240974413-ruim-aanbod-rolstoelauto-s-www-autoland-nl.html
/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1457703674-golf-6-1-2tsi-comfortline-bluemotion-77kw-2de-eigenaar.html
/a/auto-s/peugeot/m1457564187-peugeot-208-1-6-e-hdi-68kw-92pk-5-d-2014-zwart.html
/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1457124365-volkswagen-touareg-3-2-v6-177kw-4motion-aut-2004-grijs.html
/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1456753596-volkswagen-golf-vii-2-0-tdi-highline-150pk-xenon-trekhaak.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/a1001658686-200-nw-en-gebruikte-bestelwagens-personenbusjes-pick-ups.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m940111355-bus-verkopen-bestelauto-inkoop-bestelwagen-opkoper-rdw.html
/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1456401063-volkswagen-golf-1-6-74kw-2000-zwart.html
/a/auto-s/renault/m1456242548-renault-espace-2-0-dci-110kw-e4-2006-zwart.html
/a/auto-s/nissan/m1448699345-nissan-qashqai-1-5-dci-connect-2011-grijs-panoramadak.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/a1212708374-70-x-kleine-bestelwagens-lage-km-scherpe-prijzen.html
/a/auto-s/bmw/m1452641019-bmw-5-serie-2-0-520d-touring-aut-2014-grijs.html
/a/auto-s/mercedes-benz/m1448671698-mercedes-benz-a-klasse-a250-amg-224pk-7g-dct-panoramadak-wid.html
/a/auto-s/bmw/m1455671862-bmw-3-serie-2-0-i-320-cabrio-aut-2007-bruin.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m1455562699-volkswagen-transporter-kmstand-151-534-2-5-tdi-65kw-2002.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/a1295698562-35-x-renault-kangoo-2013-t-m-2015-v-a-25000-km.html
/a/auto-s/infiniti/m1458111256-infiniti-q50-3-5-hybrid-awd-2016-grijs.html
/a/auto-s/ford/m1458111166-ford-ka-1-3-i-44kw-2007-zwart.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m1457499260-renault-master-l3h2-2018-airco-camera-cruise-laadruimte-12.html
/a/auto-s/land-rover/m1458110209-land-rover-discovery-4-3-0-tdv6-2010-grijs.html
/a/auto-s/dodge/a1279463634-5-jaar-ram-dealer-garantie-lage-bijtelling.html
/a/auto-s/bmw/m1455389317-bmw-320i-e46-sedan-bieden.html
/a/auto-s/ford/m1457306473-ford-galaxy-2-0-tdci-85kw-dpf-2011-blauw.html
/a/auto-s/peugeot/m1456912876-peugeot-407-2-0-16v-sw-2006-grijs.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m1457161395-renault-master-t35-2-3-dci-l3h2-130-pk-navi-airco-camera-pdc.html
/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/a1299134880-citroen-berlingo-1-6-hdi-2017-airco-sd-3-zits-v-a-179-p-m.html
/a/auto-s/hyundai/m1458105451-hyundai-atos-gezocht-hoge-prijs-tel-0653222206.html
/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1458103618-volkswagen-polo-1-4-tsi-132kw-dsg-2012-wit.html
/a/auto-s/vrachtwagens/m1458101965-scania-torpedo.html
/a/auto-s/toyota/m1458101624-toyota-yaris-1-0-12v-vvt-i-aspiration-5dr-2012.html
/a/auto-s/dodge/a1279447576-5-jaar-ram-dealer-garantie-en-historie-bekijk-onze-website.html
```

You can also build the actual url of the page by appending `'https://www.marktplaats.nl'` to `li.a.get('href')`. So, your whole code should look like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_links(url):
    links = []
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    for li in soup.find_all(class_="mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item"):
        links.append('https://www.marktplaats.nl' + li.a.get('href'))
    return links

url = "https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/#f:10882,10898|PriceCentsTo:350000|constructionYearFrom:2001|offeredSince:TODAY|searchInTitleAndDescription:true"
links = parse_links(url)
print('\n'.join(map(str, links)))
```

It should produce the output like this:

```
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/renault/a1302508082-mooi-renault-megane-scenic-1-6-16v-aut-2005-2003-groen-airco.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/oldtimers/a1302359157-morris-minor-cabriolet-1970.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/oldtimers/a1302743902-online-veiling-oldtimers-en-classic-cars-zedelgem-vavato.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/oldtimers/a1302359138-mercedes-benz-g-500-guard-pantzer-1999.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1457703674-golf-6-1-2tsi-comfortline-bluemotion-77kw-2de-eigenaar.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/peugeot/m1457564187-peugeot-208-1-6-e-hdi-68kw-92pk-5-d-2014-zwart.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1457124365-volkswagen-touareg-3-2-v6-177kw-4motion-aut-2004-grijs.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1456753596-volkswagen-golf-vii-2-0-tdi-highline-150pk-xenon-trekhaak.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/volkswagen/a1279696849-vw-take-up-5-d-radio-airco-private-lease.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m940111355-bus-verkopen-bestelauto-inkoop-bestelwagen-opkoper-rdw.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1456401063-volkswagen-golf-1-6-74kw-2000-zwart.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/renault/m1456242548-renault-espace-2-0-dci-110kw-e4-2006-zwart.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/nissan/m1448699345-nissan-qashqai-1-5-dci-connect-2011-grijs-panoramadak.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/citroen/a1277007710-citroen-c1-feel-5-d-airco-private-lease-vanaf-189-euro-mnd.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bmw/m1452641019-bmw-5-serie-2-0-520d-touring-aut-2014-grijs.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/mercedes-benz/m1448671698-mercedes-benz-a-klasse-a250-amg-224pk-7g-dct-panoramadak-wid.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bmw/m1455671862-bmw-3-serie-2-0-i-320-cabrio-aut-2007-bruin.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m1455562699-volkswagen-transporter-kmstand-151-534-2-5-tdi-65kw-2002.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/peugeot/a1298813052-private-lease-occasion-outlet-prive-lease.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/audi/m1458114563-audi-a4-2-0-tfsi-132kw-avant-multitronic-nl-auto.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/mercedes-benz/m1452983872-mercedes-a-klasse-2-0-cdi-a200-5drs-aut-2007-grijs.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m1457499260-renault-master-l3h2-2018-airco-camera-cruise-laadruimte-12.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/infiniti/m1458111256-infiniti-q50-3-5-hybrid-awd-2016-grijs.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/a1001658686-200-nw-en-gebruikte-bestelwagens-personenbusjes-pick-ups.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/ford/m1458111166-ford-ka-1-3-i-44kw-2007-zwart.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/land-rover/m1458110209-land-rover-discovery-4-3-0-tdv6-2010-grijs.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bmw/m1455389317-bmw-320i-e46-sedan-bieden.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bestelauto-s/m1457161395-renault-master-t35-2-3-dci-l3h2-130-pk-navi-airco-camera-pdc.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/renault/a1302508082-mooi-renault-megane-scenic-1-6-16v-aut-2005-2003-groen-airco.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/ford/m1457306473-ford-galaxy-2-0-tdci-85kw-dpf-2011-blauw.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/peugeot/m1456912876-peugeot-407-2-0-16v-sw-2006-grijs.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/hyundai/m1458105451-hyundai-atos-gezocht-hoge-prijs-tel-0653222206.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/volkswagen/m1458103618-volkswagen-polo-1-4-tsi-132kw-dsg-2012-wit.html
https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/oldtimers/a1302743902-online-veiling-oldtimers-en-classic-cars-zedelgem-vavato.html
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for answering! But those URLs are not the same as the URLs of the ads on the link I provided.